# How do I pause GameObject for a couple of seconds and unpause after a couple of seconds in unity3d

Tags: c#, css, unity-game-engine, seconds, pause

I need the `gameobject` to pause on its own in my scene for 7f or 8f and un-pause at 2f on its own. The script I have is letting my pause by key. Here is my script :

```
{
```

```css
sing UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class star : MonoBehaviour {
GameObject[] pauseObjects;


 void Start () {
 pauseObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
 }
 


void pauseGameobject()

{

if()

{

start coroutine("wait");

}

}

public ienumenator wait()

{

time.timescale = 0;

yield return new waitforsceonds(7);

time.timesale = 1;

}
void pauseGameobject()

{

if()

{

start coroutine("wait");

}

}

public ienumenator wait()

{

time.timescale = 0;

yield return new waitforsceonds(7);

time.timesale = 1;

}
```

}

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "pause on its own in my scene for 7f or 8f" Do you mean pause for 7 or 8 seconds when you press P? And then unpause for only 2 seconds? What have you tried already to achieve this automatic behavior?

Comment: No . I want the game to pause for 7 seconds and unpause by itself. I don't want to press a key to pause.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear what you mean by pause on it's one, however I'm going to answer broadly, to try and help you.

If you whant to pause a single game object externally you can deactivate it and activate it accordingly with this code: `gameObject.SetActive(false);`

Instead if you want to pause the game object internally you can make a bool and in the update test wether or not it's true:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

bool update = false

public class ActiveObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start ()
    {
        //Do stuff
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if(update){
            //Do stuff
        }
        //decide wether or not to pause the game object
    }
}
```

If you want to pause the game you can set the `Time.timeScale` to `0`, or just pause all game objects.

[Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/225213/c-countdown-timer.html) you can find how to make a timer, all you need to do is count down a variable using `timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;`.

Hope I helped you,

Alex

Edit:
Ok, here is the script, keep in mind I have no way to test it ;)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class star : MonoBehaviour {
GameObject[] pauseObjects;

public float timer = 7;

float t = 0;
bool pause = false;

void Start () {
    pauseObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
    t = timer;
}



void Update() {
    if(pause){
        if(t<0){
            t=timer;
            pause = false;
            time.timescale = 1;
        }else{
            t -= Time.deltaTime;
            time.timescale = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had updated my script. I what do I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) to insert delays in the `update()` loop. Coroutines use generators, which "yield", rather than functions/methods which "return". What this allows for is code that operates asynchronously while still being written in a linear fashion.

The built in coroutine you're most likely looking for is [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html). To start a coroutine you simply call `StarCoroutine()` and pass in any method of type `IEnumerator`. This method will `yield` periodically. In the following example, `WaitForSeconds(5)` will yield after 5 seconds. Fractions of a second can also be used, represented by floats, for example 2.5 would be two and a half seconds.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WaitForSecondsExample : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start() {
        StartCoroutine(Example());
    }

    IEnumerator Example() {
        Debug.Log(Time.time); // time before wait
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        Debug.Log(Time.time); // time after wait
    }
}
```